# Futures - map vs flatmap

Tags: scala, future

I've read the docs about `map` and `flatMap` and I understand that `flatMap` is used for an operation that accepts a `Future` parameter and returns another `Future`. What I don't fully understand is why I would want to do this. Take this example:

1. User hits my webservice asking to "do stuff"
2. I download a file (which is slow)
3. I process the file (which is CPU intensive)
4. Render the result

I understand that I would want to use a future to download the file but I have have two options re processing it:

```
val downloadFuture = Future {/* downloadFile */}
val processFuture = downloadFuture map {/* processFile */}
processFuture onSuccess { case r => renderResult(r) }
```

or

```
val downloadFuture = Future {/* download the file */}
val processFuture = downloadFuture flatMap { Future {/* processFile */} }
processFuture onSuccess { case r => renderResult(r) }
```

By adding debug statements (`Thread.currentThread().getId`) I see that in both cases download, `process` and `render` occur in the same thread (using `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`).

Would I use `flatMap` simply to decouple `downloadFile` and `processFile` and ensure that `processFile` always runs in a `Future` even if it was not mapped from `downloadFile`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> ensure that `processFile` always runs in a `Future` even if it was not mapped from `downloadFile`?

Yes that is correct.

However most of the time you wouldn't use `Future { ... }` directly, you would use functions (from other libraries or your own) which return a `Future`.

Imagine the following functions :

```
def getFileNameFromDB{id: Int) : Future[String] = ???
def downloadFile(fileName: String) : Future[java.io.File] = ???
def processFile(file: java.io.File) : Future[ProcessResult] = ???
```

You could use `flatMap` to combine them :

```
val futResult: Future[ProcessResult] =
  getFileNameFromDB(1).flatMap( name =>
    downloadFile(name).flatMap( file =>
       processFile(file)
    )
  )
```

Or using a for comprehension :

```
val futResult: Future[ProcessResult] =
  for {
    name <- getFileNameFromDB(1)
    file <- downloadFile(name)
    result <- processFile(file)
  } yield result
```

Most of the time you would not call `onSuccess` (or `onComplete`). By using one of these functions you register a callback function which will be executed when the `Future` finishes.

If in our example you would like to render the result of the file processing, you would return something like `Future[Result]` instead of calling `futResult.onSuccess(renderResult)`. In the last case your return type would be `Unit`, so you can not really return something.

In Play Framework this could look like :

```
def giveMeAFile(id: Int) = Action.async {
  for {
    name <- getFileNameFromDB(1)
    file <- downloadFile(name)
    processed <- processFile(file)
  } yield Ok(processed.byteArray).as(processed.mimeType))
}
```

Answer (score 43):

If you have a future, let's say, `Future[HttpResponse]`, and you want to specify what to do with that result when it is ready, such as write the body to a file, you may do something like `responseF.map(response => write(response.body)`. However if `write` is also an asynchronous method which returns a future, this `map` call will return a type like `Future[Future[Result]]`.

In the following code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val numF = Future{ 3 }

val stringF = numF.map(n => Future(n.toString))

val flatStringF = numF.flatMap(n => Future(n.toString))
```

`stringF` is of type `Future[Future[String]]` while `flatStringF` is of type `Future[String]`. Most would agree, the second is more useful. Flat Map is therefore useful for composing multiple futures together.

When you use `for` comprehensions with Futures, under the hood `flatMap` is being used together with `map`.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val threeF = Future(3)
val fourF = Future(4)
val fiveF = Future(5)

val resultF = for{
  three <- threeF
  four <- fourF
  five <- fiveF
}yield{
  three * four * five
}

Await.result(resultF, 3 seconds)
```

This code will yield 60.

Under the hood, scala translates this to

```
val resultF = threeF.flatMap(three => fourF.flatMap(four => fiveF.map(five => three * four * five)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = 
  this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => f(a)
  }
```

This is a simple example where how the flatMap works for Option, this can help to understand better, It is actually composing it is not adding a wrapper again.That's what we need.

Answer (score 0):

Failure possibility from transformation function another reason why there exists `flatMap` on Future.

say you have a `f: Future[T]`. and a transformation `func: T => B`. however this func could fail due to some reason. so we want to indicate the caller it has failed.

with just `Future.map` it's not obvious how to achieve this. but with `flatMap` you can. because with `flatMap` it takes Future as return, and you can then easily do Future.failed(e) to bubble up the error to the caller. or if it succeeded, you can then use Future.success(r) to return the result.

aka. turn func into `func: T => Future[B]`

this is very useful when you are chaining operations with Future and operations could fail in the middle.