# Unable to use for comprehension to resolve Future

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I have this `Action` which should return a `Future[Result]` but I am unable to code it using `for` comprehension. This is the first time I am using `for` comprehension so I am also not sure if this is how I should use `for`.

Also, would someone comment on whether the usage of `for` is correct?

```
def verifyUser(token:String) = Action.async{
    implicit request => { //the function takes a token
      val tokenFutureOption:Future[Option[UserToken]] = userTokenRepo.find(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token))) //checkc if the token exists in the db (db returns a Future)
      for(tokenOption<- tokenFutureOption) yield { //resolve the future
        tokenOption match {  
          case Some(userToken) =>{//token exists
            val userOptionFuture = userRepo.findUser(userToken.loginInfo)//find user to which the token belongs. Another db request which returns a Future
            for(userOption <- userOptionFuture) yield {//resolve future
              userOption match {
                case Some(user) =>{//user exists
                  val newInternalProfile = user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.copy(confirmed=true) //modify user's profile
                  val newProfile = UserProfile(Some(newInternalProfile),user.profile.externalProfileDetails)
                  val confirmedUser = user.copy(profile=newProfile)
                  val userOptionFuture :Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.updateUser(confirmedUser) //update profile with new value. Another db operation with returns a Future
                  for(userOption <- userOptionFuture) yield {//resolve future
                  userTokenRepo.remove(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))//remove the token
              //      Ok("user verified") //I WANT TO RETURN SUCCESS RESPONSE HERE BUT CODE DOESN'T COMPILE IF I UNCOMMENT THIS
                  }
                }
                case None =>{ //user doesn't exist
            //      Ok("user verified") //I WANT TO RETURN FAILURE RESPONSE HERE BUT CODE DOESN'T COMPILE IF I UNCOMMENT THIS
                }
              }
            }    
          }
          case None =>{//INVALID TOKEN RECEIVED
            Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config //I CAN RETURN Redirect (WHICH IS OF SAME TYPE AS OK I.E. RESULT) BUT WHY AM I NOT ABLE TO USE OK ABOVE
          }
        }

      }//THIS IS THE END OF FIRST FOR LOOP. HOW DO I HANDLE FAILURES IN THE FUTURE?

    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the actual bug? Meaning, what is the code **currently doing** and what **should** it be doing ? The answer to these questions should be within the body of your question itself, not just in the comments. Long comments are difficult to read.

Comment: This sounds like a job for OptionT from cats.

Comment: thanks. So I couldn't do it with just `for`? If I use combination of `map` and `flatMap`, I can flatten out the `Future[Future[]]`. Is there a way to flatten out `Future[Future[]]` if I am using `for` inside a `for`? The issue seem to be that `verifyUser` expects a `Future[Result]`. But if I do `for(tokenOption<- tokenFutureOption) yield {` and inside it I use another `for(userOption <- userOptionFuture)` then it will generate a `Future[Future[]]`. Isn't it?

Comment: I have created another question which probably has better description of what I am trying to achieve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374752/is-there-an-equivalent-of-flattening-return-values-if-i-use-for-comprehension-wi

Comment: This question has been duplicated and abandoned, so I suggest it is put on hold ("unclear").

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Future`, `Option` which are Monads and the idea behind them being helpful to sequence the computations just like `Functor`s but also with capability to specify what happens next. `.flatMap` is what Monads have allow that which can be used as `for yield` for readability.

So in your example you can compose the api using sequence of operations.

```
  object Api {

    final case class UserTokenKey(uuid: UUID)
    final case class UserToken(loginInfo: String)

    object userTokenRepo {
      def find(u: UserTokenKey) = {
        Future.successful(Some(UserToken(loginInfo = "foundLoginInfo")))
      }

      def remove(u: UserTokenKey) = {
        Future.successful(Some(UserToken(loginInfo = "")))
      }
    }

    final case class User(profile: String)

    object userRepo {
      def findUser(u: String) = {
        Future.successful(Some(User("profile")))
      }

      def updateUser(u: User) = {
        Future.successful(Some(User("updated profile")))
      }
    }

    def verifyUser(token: String)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) = {

      val user: Future[Option[UserToken]] = for {
        tokenMaybe: Option[UserToken] <- userTokenRepo.find(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))
        userMaybe: Option[User] <- 
          tokenMaybe match {
            case Some(t) => userRepo.findUser(t.loginInfo)
            case _ => Future.successful(Option.empty[User])
          }
        updatedUserMaybe: Option[User] <- 
          userMaybe match {
          case Some(u) => userRepo.updateUser(u)
          case _ => Future.successful(Option.empty[User])
        }
        removedUserMaybe: Option[UserToken] <- userTokenRepo.remove(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))
      } yield removedUserMaybe

      user
    }

    def httpLayer(request: String) = {
      import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
      import play.api.mvc.Results

      verifyUser(request).onComplete {
        case Success(Some(user)) =>
          println("user verified")
          Results.Ok("user verified")
        case Success(None) =>
          println("user does not exist")
          Results.Ok("user does not exist")
        case Failure(f) =>
          println("unknown error")
          Results.Ok("unknown error")
      }

    }

  }
```

Now you can test your api as below

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    import Api._

    httpLayer(UUID.randomUUID().toString) // user verified

  }
```

***Note1***: you might want to use api to respond `Future[Either[Error, User]]` to better handle errors and use `Error` to determine what to respond back to the http consumers.

**Note2**: Since you are working with two monads `Future[Option[a]]`, you can combine them using [Monad Transformation](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) `OptionT[OuterMonad, Value Type]` in [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/OptionT.scala) or cats mtl library. Which gives a single monad `OptionT`.

```
def verifyUserV2(tokenString: String)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) = {

      import scalaz._
      import Scalaz._

      // import cats.implicits._
      // import cats.data.OptionT

      val userStack = for {
        token       <- OptionT(userTokenRepo.find(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(tokenString))))
        user        <- OptionT(userRepo.findUser(token.loginInfo))
        updatedUser <- OptionT(userRepo.updateUser(user))
        removedUser <- OptionT(userTokenRepo.remove(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(tokenString))))
      } yield removedUser

      userStack.run
      //cats unpack stack
      // userStack.value
}
```

Useful reads:

- [Futures - map vs flatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31641529/432903)
- [Using Either to process failures in Scala code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194541/432903)