# is there an equivalent of flattening return values if I use for comprehension within for comprehension

Tags: scala

In the following two functions, `someF1` will not compile but `someF2` will. It's because `someF1` is expected to return `Future[Int]` but it returns `Future[Future[Int]]` because I am using a `for` within a `for`. I don't face issue in `someF2` because I am flattening `Future[Future[]]` in `someF2`. Is there an equivalent way of flattening results if I use embedded `for` or is `someF1` a wrong use case of `for` and I should use it only to execute `Futures` in parallel and not in sequence?

```
  // Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def someF1:Future[Int] = {
  val f1 = Future[Int]{1}

  for(i<-f1) yield{
    if(i == 0) {
      val f2 = Future{2}
      for(j<-f2) yield {i+j} //this will make function return Future[Future[Int]]
    }
    else {
      val f3 = Future{3}
      for(k<-f3) yield {i+k}//this will make function return Future[Future[Int]]
    }
  }
}

// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def someF2:Future[Int] = {
  val f1 = Future[Int]{1}

  f1.flatMap{i=> //flatMap will flatten Future[Future[Int]]
    if(i == 0) {
      val f2 = Future{2}
      f2.map(j=> {i+j})
    }
    else {
      val f3 = Future{3}
      f3.map(k=>{i+k})
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is that, with a `for` comprehension, the final generator (i.e. `<-`) is translated into a `map()` call. Every other generator is a `flatMap()`call. So, no, you can't achieve what you're after using nested `for`. That creates too many `map()` calls and not enough `flatMap()` calls.

This will work:

```
def someF1:Future[Int] = {
  val f1 = Future[Int]{1}

  for {
    i <- f1
    j <- Future(2)
    k <- Future(3)
  } yield {
    if (i == 0) i+j
    else        i+k
  }
}
```

But in that case you are launching one more `Future` than you actually need.

Comment: well explained. Thanks

Comment: could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373295/unable-to-use-for-comprehension-to-resolve-future. This is my main issue. Basically, I am doing several database queries each of which return a Future and whether to do the next database query depends on the result of previous one. I am able to code it using `flatMap` and `map` but not with `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @jwvh's answer

You can still avoid the sencond future evaluation with the following, *more complicated*, piece of code:

```
def someF1:Future[Int] =
  for {
    i <- Future[Int]{1}
    r <- if (i == 0) {
        for (j <- Future[Int]{2}) yield i + j
      } else {
        for (k <- Future[Int]{3}) yield i + k
      }
  } yield r
```

Also, I would recommend you to take a look at the [documentation of for/yield](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html)

Comment: I'll look at this. Maybe this is what I need for the issue I am trying to resolve - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373295/unable-to-use-for-comprehension-to-resolve-future